# "echo -e" not working in su -c command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to do the following:

```
su username -c "echo -e "test 1""
```

When I do that, it outputs:

```
-e test
```

If I try this:

```
su username -c "echo -e 'test 1'"
```

Output:

```
-e test 1
```

Tried this:

```
su username -c 'echo -e "test 1"'
```

Output:

```
-e test 1
```

How can I get this to work so it outputs the string without the -e escape flag?

Comment: `echo -e` isn't actually even *legal*. As in, an `echo` implementation that provides it all is violating the POSIX specification.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- yes, bash violates the spec out-of-the-box, but if both `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are set it conforms, so any code that you write that depends on `echo -e` is fragile.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me...

Comment: @arkascha, do you mean the OP's code works for you, or that `echo -e` works for you (and thus you're using a non-POSIX-compliant shell)? *Lots* of people use non-POSIX-compliant shells. That doesn't mean that writing code that will break on a shell that actually *does* comply with the standard is a good thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are absolutely right in all you state. All I said is: the OPs code works for me. It was meant as a comment to clarify that this is not generally borked somehow.

Answer (score 2):

First, your quotes aren't nesting the way you want them to. To fix this might look like:

```
su username -c 'echo -e "test 1"'
```

...or...

```
su username -c "echo -e \"test 1\""
```

If you want to guarantee the child shell to be bash (which supports `echo -e` in the manner you expect by default), consider:

```
su username -c 'bash -s' <<'EOF'
echo -e "test 1"
EOF
```

---

Second, **there's no guarantee that `echo` will provide a `-e` option at all** (on an echo compliant with [the relevant standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), `echo -e` will print `-e` on its output), so your code shouldn't be depending on such an argument being available.

The POSIX equivalent to bash's `echo -e` (when enabled, which it isn't always) is `printf '%b'`:

```
su username -c "printf '%b\n' 'test 1'"
```

...if you don't actually want the behavior of `-e` (interpolating backslash-escapes in content, as opposed to in the format string alone), use `%s` instead of `%b`.

Comment: What's the difference between using `%b` with a literal string, rather than just writing the string?

Comment: @TomFenech, `echo -e "test 1"` doesn't contain any backslash escapes at all, so since the OP claims to actually need `-e`, presumably their real code/situation is more interesting. If they have content with literal escapes in a variable and they want to print that variable with those escapes evaluated, you wouldn't want any `%`s in the variable to be treated as substitution placeholders, hence `%b` (honoring backslashes, but not `%` expansion placeholders).

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that `echo` is the POSIX equivalent to `bash`'s `echo -e`, since the `-e` flag simply turns on behavior that POSIX `echo` already has. Using `printf` is just a way to avoid worrying about which `echo` you have.

Comment: @chepner, ...not all POSIX echo, but XSI-extended POSIX echo only. Thus, even if you know your `echo` is POSIX-compliant, you still can only be certain about behavior with `printf` unless you have a guarantee about whether XSI extensions are present.